# Partial derivative with respect to metric tensor $\frac{\partial}{\partial{g_{kn}}}(g_{pj}g_{ql})$

Tags: physics, partial-derivative, tensors, general-relativity

$$-\frac{1}{4\mu_0}F^{pq}F^{jl} \frac{\partial}{\partial{g_{kn}}}(g_{pj}g_{ql})=+\frac{1}{4\mu_0} F^{pq} F^{lj} 2 \delta^k_p \delta^n_j g_{ql}$$

I need to know how to derive $\frac{\partial}{\partial{g_{kn}}}(g_{pj}g_{ql})$. Can you explain how the final result on the right side was obtained?

Comment: Are you sure about the sign?

Comment: @John:  I think the sign is OK since as I recall $F^{lj}$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: Yes, I think $F^{jl}$ is an anti-symmetric tensor, i.e. $F^{jl}=-F^{lj}$

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of the symmetry of the metric tensor (which is what I'm assuming $g_{pq}$ is).

Clearly,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial g_{kn}} (g_{pj}g_{ql}) = \frac{\partial g_{pj}}{ \partial g_{kn}} g_{ql} + g_{pj} \frac{\partial g_{ql}}{\partial g_{kn}} 
$$

The partial derivative in this expression must give something symmetric. For a non-symmetric tensor $a$, all 9 components are independent and $\dfrac{\partial a_{pq}}{\partial a_{kn}}$ is non-zero only when $p=k$ and $q=n$, i.e. you have

$$
\dfrac{\partial a_{pq}}{\partial a_{kn}} = \delta_{p}^{k} \delta_{q}^{n}
$$

For a symmetric tensor, $g_{ij}=g_{ji}$ so you can't do that. Instead, you must symmetrize the argument by rewriting it as

$$g_{pj} = \frac{1}{2} (a_{pj} + a_{jp})
$$

Now take partial derivatives using the formula derived above for the non-symmetric tensor.
You'll get

$$\frac{\partial g_{pj}}{\partial g_{kn}} = \frac{1}{2} (\delta_{p}^{k} \delta_{j}^{n} + \delta_{j}^{k} \delta_{p}^{n}) \\
$$

You can proceed similarly for the other term $\dfrac{\partial g_{ql}}{\partial g_{kn}}$.
Finally you have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial g_{kn}} (g_{pj}g_{ql}) = \frac{1}{2} (\delta_{p}^{k} \delta_{j}^{n} + \delta_{j}^{k} \delta_{p}^{n}) g_{ql} + \frac{1}{2} (\delta_{q}^{k} \delta_{l}^{n} + \delta_{l}^{k} \delta_{q}^{n}) g_{pj} 
$$

Now consider the contraction of this expression with $F^{pq} F^{jl}$ and proceed.

Comment: Thanks but I am unable to get to $2\delta^k_p \delta^n_j g_{ql}$ from
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial g_{kn}} (g_{pj}g_{ql}) = \frac{1}{2} (\delta_{p}^{k} \delta_{j}^{n} + \delta_{j}^{k} \delta_{p}^{n}) g_{ql} + \frac{1}{2} (\delta_{q}^{k} \delta_{l}^{n} + \delta_{l}^{k} \delta_{q}^{n}) g_{pj} 
$$

Comment: This is the farthest I could get after the contraction:

I had to post multiple comments since it's too long.
$$
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{4\mu_0}F^{pq} F^{jl} \frac{\partial}{\partial{g_{kn}}}(g_{pj} g_{ql}) & = -\frac{1}{4\mu_0} \frac{1}{2} \left( F^{pq} F^{jl} \delta^k_p \delta^n_jg_{ql} + F^{pq} F^{jl} \delta^k_j \delta^n_p g_{ql} + F^{pq} F^{jl}\delta^k_q \delta^n_l g_{pj} + F^{pq} F^{jl}  \delta^k_l\delta^n_q g_{pj}  \right) \\
 & = -\frac{1}{4\mu_0} \frac{1}{2} \left( F^{kq} F^{nl}g_{ql} +  F^{nq} F^{kl}g_{ql} +  F^{pk} F^{jn}g_{pj} +  F^{pn} F^{jk}g_{pj}  \right) \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Interchanging the dummy indexes in the 3rd and 4th terms $p\Longleftrightarrow q$ and $j\Longleftrightarrow l$:

$$
= -\frac{1}{4\mu_0} \frac{1}{2} \left( F^{kq} F^{nl}g_{ql} +  F^{nq} F^{kl}g_{ql} +  F^{qk} F^{ln}g_{ql} +  F^{qn} F^{lk}g_{ql}  \right)
$$ 
 and because $F^{ab}$ is an anti-symmetric tensor (i.e. $F^{ab} = -F^{ba}$):

Comment: $$\begin{align}
& = -\frac{1}{4\mu_0} \frac{1}{2} \left( 2 F^{kq} F^{nl}g_{ql} + 2 F^{nq} F^{kl}g_{ql}  \right) \\
& = -\frac{1}{4\mu_0}  \left(  F^{kq} F^{nl}g_{ql} +  F^{nq} F^{kl}g_{ql}  \right) \\
& = -\frac{1}{4\mu_0}  \left(  F^{kq} F^{n}_q +  F^{nq} F^{k}_q  \right) \\
\end{align}
$$